# Image Buttons showing in solution but not on my hosted website

Tags: asp.net, button, visual-studio-2013, uiimage

I am creating an online portfolio, the navigation bar works when I test it in a build a solution on Visual Studio using Google Chrome, but when I publish my site the buttons are no where to be seen, can anyone shed any light on this error?

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/HomeTag.png" style="margin-left: 115px; margin-top: 16px" PostBackUrl="~/Homepage.aspx" />
<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton2" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/AboutTag.png" style="margin-left: 146px" PostBackUrl="~/About.aspx" />
<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton3" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/PortfolioTag.png" style="margin-left: 158px" />
<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton4" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/MoreWorkTag.png" style="margin-left: 114px" />
<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton5" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/ContactTag.png" style="margin-left: 90px" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you uploaded your images to the website? Is it in the directory you expect? You could try manually navigating to view the images to see if they do exist as you expect:

```
"{your-website-url}/Images/ContactTag.png"
```

Comment: Yeah the images are in the image folder